# CHEF Cloud provision support

Tags: chef-infra, devops, chef-recipe

Does Chef allow provisioning, creating instances, to "all clouds", meaning some that are unpopular?

I only find driver for aws, gcp ...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef-provisioning is, in general, no longer under heavy development. Only the AWS and Fog drivers for it are recommended at all, and even that is with a lot of caveats.

Comment: is it feasible to develop a driver to accomodate the cloud that i need ?

Comment: I mean that's up to you but if you have to ask, probably not. You should almost certainly be using Terraform.